# how can I show error messages from responses from the server in form of alert message in MERN project?

Tags: alert, mern, error-messaging

I want to show error responses or some kind of messages got from responses from the server as alert message to my user. right now, i am only printing messages in console

Answer (score 0):

You can use toastify to display the error messages received from the backend.

```
npm i react-toastify
```

example:
`toast(response.msg)`

For more details, please refer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toastify.

Comment: firstly i have to add error message into store where all data is stored???

Comment: No, that is not needed I think. You can just print the messages as it is, when hitting the API.

Comment: but i calling my in different file then i defined it so how can i use toastify in these situation??

Comment: but i defined my code for api calling in different file and i am calling it from different file so i have to store it in store i created

Comment: In case if it is a small application, it'll be okay for storing the responses. But it is not recommended to store the responses in the local-storage.

Comment: no no not it local storage, i am storing it in redux state

Comment: but thank you, problem is solved!!